# Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of the first index of a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that takes in a list of tuples (the first index of each tuple is an int and the second index a char) and an integer and will return the number of occurrences in the first index of each tuple. So far I have:

```
counter :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int 
counter [] find = 0
counter ys find = length xs
    where xs = [xs | xs <- ys, xs == find]
```

For example, if I run:

`counter [(3,"a"),(4,"b"),(2,"a"), (3, "f"),(3,"t")] 3`

This should return 3 since there are 3 tuples in the list where the first index is 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *unpack* the 2-tuple and check the first item, so:

```
counter :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> Int 
counter ys find = length [ x | (x,_) <- ys, x == find]
```

or with [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
counter :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> Int 
counter ys find = length (filter ((find ==) . fst) ys)
```